# Access javascript variable included in HTML header from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a javascript file included in the `<head></head>` tags of my Angular 2 app. I would like to access a function in that javascript file from my typescript file, how should I do that? When I'm running the app, I can type `var simplemde = new SimpleMDE()` in the browser console to get my markdown editor working, but how can I do this in the constructor in my typescript file?

Comment: Start with some code. Show both your files (or part of them). So people can look at a specific example, not answer for something abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it at the top of your component or wherever you need it like so:

```js
declare var SimpleMDE: any;
```

Then you can call it in your constructor like you want!

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`. I declared the variable above my component, and in my constructor I have `let simplemde = new SimpleMDE();`

Comment: When doing `var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, I put that in the first line of my constructor.

Comment: In my header tags I have `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>` and in the typescript file I have `declare var SimpleMDE(): any; @Component({...}) export class MDEditor{constructor(){let simplemde = new SimpleMDE();}}` @rinukkusu

Comment: Please try declaring it without the paranthesis.

Comment: Could I download the javascript file and import it into my typescript file? If so , could I just do `import * as mde from 'js/simplemde.min.js';` and use it like `var simplemde = new mde.SimpleMDE();`?

Comment: Yeah, sure, but you need typings with it or use that 'declare' approach I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**namespacing**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/), which is basically an object and it wraps all other variable & function

Like this

```
var SomeObject={}
SomeObject.abc = "Some Value";
SOmeObject.myFunction = function(){
  // function body
}
```

In other file you can simply call `SomeObject.abc` & it will return string `Some Value`

You should use namespacing to avoid conflict of global window